# Insert Javascript Wrap around Siblings

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have a requirement to wrap a div form-inline and form-group around siblings of an element

```
<div class="condition row m-t-10">
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
</div>
```

**Goal Via Javascript**

```
<div class="condition row m-t-10">
  <div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I have tried many attempts using "before", "after", "wrap" and everything seems to invoke around the "condition" div. I need it to start right after that element.

**Failed Attempt**

```
var row_control = $( "div.condition.row.m-t-10" ).siblings();
row_control.wrap("<div><div>").before();
```

Comment: are you using jquery or can you only use straight JS? Also what have you tried already? and what isnt woring

Comment: I have been trying to achieve this through jquery. http://api.jquery.com/wrap/  and http://api.jquery.com/siblings/. What is happening is when I invoke the .before() or .after(); it will wrap the parent <div class="condition row m-t-10"> not the siblings

Comment: I am trying to have it locate <div class="condition row m-t-10"> as the parent and then insert the required div tags I need as a wrap of the siblings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's [wrapInner()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/) is what you want:

```
$('.condition').wrapInner('<div class="form-group"></div>').wrapInner('<div class="form-inline"></div>');
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mt1uw3nb/)

Comment: I knew I was missing something! Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. You were on the right track with `wrap`, but working outward rather than inward :)